# How to use Mono library in .NET Core 3 project on Linux?

Tags: .net, linux, winforms, .net-core

I'd like to port a .NET library that is referencing `System.Windows.Forms` to .NET Core 3. While developing on Linux using Visual Studio Code, Omnisharp etc.

My current understanding is, that this is not possible as Windows Forms needs... well Windows. But what about the Mono libraries? I know the library runs on Linux using Mono (which contains `System.Windows.Forms`).

Can I reference those Mono libraries to get my .NET Core 3 project to build on Linux?

Comment: If this question is nonsense please leave a short comment. Just to vote down unfortunately doesn't help.

Comment: Windows Forms is excluded from cross platform by Microsoft for reasons. The Mono implementation has significant issues (especial on macOS). While of course someone might fix those issues in the long run, you really should consider an alternative, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea Again, Mono WinForms has been asked tons of times here, and I guess that's why you got down voted.

Answer (score 0):

To reference a library in .NET Core that library would have to be published using .NET Standard (Or course .NET Core too). I do not believe the built in framework libraries from Mono are published individually and/or have been ported to .NET Standard. I think will you need to move to a different UI library if you want it to work cross platform.

Comment: Only the last sentence is correct. The first two are incorrect for reasons.

Comment: 1) "have to be published using .NET Standard"? Not necessary. 2)  "I do not believe the built in framework libraries from Mono are published individually and/or have been ported to .NET Core"? Even before .NET Core 1.0 RTM, Mono WinForms has been ported for experiments and it worked then. Those experiments did not move on, as Mono WinForms had its own issues and is not worth the while.

Comment: @LexLi feel free to edit my response to correct it then.